# Does considering a pair of vacuously true statements lead to a contradiction?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

If $A$ is false, then both $A \Rightarrow B$ as well as $A \Rightarrow \lnot B$ are true.

Consider any $X \subset M$.

$ \forall \alpha, \alpha \in \emptyset \Rightarrow \alpha \in X$ is true, since $ \alpha \in \emptyset $ is always false.

Therefore, $\emptyset \subset X$   $......(1) $

$ \exists \alpha, \alpha \in \emptyset \Rightarrow \alpha \notin X$ is also vacuously true for the same reason.

Thus, $\emptyset \not \subset X$   $..........(2) $

$(1)$ and $(2)$ lead to a contradiction.

Comment: Everything is correct except (2)

Comment: $ \exists \alpha, \alpha \in \emptyset \Rightarrow \alpha \notin X$ is also true, isn't it? For  $\alpha \in \emptyset $ is false?

Comment: $\exists\alpha~. (\alpha\in\emptyset\to\alpha\notin X)$ maybe true, but *not* equivalent to $\emptyset\nsubseteq X$. That would be $\exists\alpha~.(\alpha\in\emptyset\wedge\alpha\notin X)$ (and it is false). @PragnyaJha

Comment: Just to (sort of) answer the title of the question: All unicorns are green, all unicorns are pink, and there is no contradiction there as long as there are no unicorns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second statement is not entirely correct.

The relation $A \nsubseteq B$ means that 
$$(\exists x) \big( x\in A \, \wedge \, x\notin B \big)$$
but it doesn't mean that
$$(\exists x) \big( x\in A \, \Rightarrow \, x\notin B \big)$$

Answer (score 1):

How do you conclude that *"Thus, $\varnothing\not\subset X$"*? By definition
$$\varnothing\subset X\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad(\forall x)(x\in\varnothing\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ x\in X),$$
where the latter is vacuously true, as you already note yourself.

Comment: $ \exists \alpha, \alpha \in \emptyset \Rightarrow \alpha \notin X$ is also true, isn't it? For  $\alpha \in \emptyset $ is false?